# Combining lists to create points to plot with ListLinePlot

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to make a `ListLinePlot` using these lists:

```
distance = {0, 5, 25, 45, 65, 85, 105, 125, 145, 150};
trial1 = {0, 0.14, .49, 0.94, 1.39, 1.85, 2.43, 3.08, 3.61, 4.31};
```

and I would like to get something that looks like this:

```
{{0, 0}, {5, 0.14}, {25, 0.49}, ... ,{150, 4.76}}
```

Is there a function or efficient, convenient method I can employ to quickly combine the two lists and form a list shown above instead of painstakingly and inefficiently creating an entirely new list?

For those of you confused about my uneven lists above, I cleaned it up after many many months.

Comment: Look up `Transpose[]`.

Comment: Your lists don't have the same length.

Comment: You can do it in this way: Thread@{distance, trial1}. Please obey the hint from @march!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem can be solved with a one-liner.

```
ListLinePlot[Thread[{distance, trial1[[;; -2]]}]]
```

[image: plot]

Of course if the data are trimmed before plotting than

```
ListLinePlot[Thread[{distance, trial1}]]
```

will do.

Comment: Yet another way: `ListLinePlot[Select[Flatten[{distance, trial1}, {{2}, {1}}], Length[#] == 2 &]]`

Comment: Thank you, m_goldberg for the help! This is very helpful. A follow-up question: how would you create a line or curve of best fit for the graph?

Comment: @GumpyCede. Follow-up questions should be put to the whole community, either by editing the original question or (better) by asking a new question. But I'll give you a hint -- follow [this link](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/DoStatisticalAnalysis.html) and click on the links there that mention *models* or *regression*.

Answer (score 4):

I removed the last element of trail1 as per comment by @march. Lookup this site:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513010/how-to-combine-two-lists-to-plot-coordinate-pairs

```
distance = {0, 5, 25, 45, 65, 85, 105, 125, 145, 150}; 

trial1 = {0, 0.14, 0.49, 0.94, 1.39, 1.85, 2.43, 3.08, 3.61, 4.31}; 

Partition[Riffle[distance, trial1], 2]

(* {{0, 0}, {5, 0.14}, {25, 0.49}, {45, 0.94}, {65, 1.39}, {85, 1.85}, 
    {105, 2.43}, {125, 3.08}, {145, 3.61}, {150, 4.31}}*)
```